# Convert dates like 13JAN into DDMMM

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
  status_tot LastVisit Balance
  5 13JAN2016     228
  4 23SEP2013      20
  5 19NOV2013     220
  5 24MAR2014    6750
  5 25AUG2016    1426
  5 23SEP2013      20
```

I am looking for an easy way to convert dates like `13JAN2016` into `13012016`. Any thoughts on how I can easily accomplish this?

Comment: This is stored in some table? You want to update data?

Comment: Are those dates in character or calendar format?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a SAS date change the format:

```
Format date ddmmyy8.;
```